# How do I create an animated 3D day night cycle in godot?

Tags: graphics, game-development, godot

I am trying to create a 3d game in godot and I have been wondering how I would go about creating a day/night cycle. I would assume I would use shaders but I have found no resources on the subject. My idea to have a directional light as the sun but from there I do not know where to go. EX. how would I know when the sky should be a certain color?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This video has a very good description of what it takes to make a sky shader in Godot. The only downside is that it needs to constantly update the lighting , which is generally too costly to perform every frame. The video has a solution which is to skip some frames before redrawing, which doesn't give a perfectly smooth transition, but still it looks pretty good. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2YWV1NWwGY

Comment: I will look into that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad topic and therefore as a whole not very suitable for a stack overflow question. I'll focus on the last part of the question ("how would I know when the sky should be a certain color"), because that is a well focussed question. You will have to figure out the rest on your own (directional light is certainly an option).

Godot does not keep the time for you. But you get the length of the current frame in the delta parameter of the _process function. You can sum up the value of delta over every frame which gives you the number of real seconds since the game started.

Usually time passes faster in game than in the real world. You need to decide on a factor that specifies how much faster. If you divide the summed up delta time by this factor you get the number of in-game seconds since the game started. Take that modulo the number of in-game seconds in an in-game day and you have the time of day.

How to map the time of day to sky colours is up to you again.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I have decided on using a gradient function based on the sun's angle which is based upon the time. So when the sun's angle is zero it would be orange at the horizon and a dark blue straight up with a gradient in between. P.S. Sorry for the broad question but thank you again for the insight.